# Match first date in line with regex

Tags: regex, date, notepad++

I'm trying to write a regex search string for Notepad++ that will match the first date on every line.

My text looks something like this:

> Nå skal folk få fred, iTromsø, 09.09.2017 19:09 Martin Lægland, Publisert på nett.
>   Nå skal folk få fred, iTromsø, 09.09.2017,  Martin Lægland 31.12.2017 Publisert på nett.
>   Nå skal folk få fred, iTromsø, 09.09.2017 19:09 Martin Lægland, Publisert på nett.

I only want the first date on each line, so excluding `31.12.2017` on the second line.

I've tried `\K(([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{4}))`, but that only gives me the second date, not the first.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please share your attempts for us not to repeat the same efforts.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, I've tried updating now. My first question on Stackoverflow :)

Comment: @ThomasTallaksen you can use `^.*?\K\d+\.\d+\.\d+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/aABRhm/1)

```
^.*?\K\d+\.\d+\.\d+
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
Nå skal folk få fred, iTromsø, 09.09.2017 19:09 Martin Lægland, Publisert på nett.
Nå skal folk få fred, iTromsø, 09.09.2017, Martin Lægland 31.12.2017 Publisert på nett.
Nå skal folk få fred, iTromsø, 09.09.2017 19:09 Martin Lægland, Publisert på nett.
```

#### Output

```
09.09.2017
09.09.2017
09.09.2017
```

---

#### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `.*?` Match any character any number of times, but as few as possible
- `\K` Reset the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `\d+\.\d+\.\d+` Match any digit one or more times, followed by a dot `.` literally, followed by the same thing (any digit one or more times, followed by a dot `.` literally), followed by any digit one or more times

Comment: +1, since you cracked it first, I would request you to include quantifiers instead of any number of hits

Comment: @SriniV thanks, I was going to use specific quantifiers, but I don't think it's absolutely necessary based on the nature of the input's format. The OP could use your solution if specifying quantifiers is integral to solving their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Full credit to ctwheels. With a different flavour of it to have boundaries defined

```
^.*?\K[0-9]{2}+\.[0-9]{2}+\.[0-9]{4}+
```

**Explanation:**

```
^ asserts position at start of the string
.*? matches any character (except for line terminators)
*? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
\K resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]{2}+
{2}+ Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 - 9 
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]{2}+
{2}+ Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 - 9 
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]{4}+
{4}+ Quantifier — Matches exactly 4 times
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 - 9 
Global pattern flags
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
```

Comment: `{4}+` is equal to `{4}` as you cannot match *exactly* 4 chars in a possessive, greedy or lazy way. It will always attempt to match 4 occurrences.