# Reference regex when using find and replace in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I use this regex `^.*?\K\d+\.\d+\.\d+` to search for the first date on every line in notepad++. It seems to work just fine.

The text I work with looks something like this:

> Nå skal folk få fred, iTromsø, 09.09.2017 19:09 Martin Lægland, Publisert på nett.
>   Nå skal folk få fred, iTromsø, 09.09.2017,  Martin Lægland 31.12.2017 Publisert på nett.
>   Nå skal folk få fred, iTromsø, 09.09.2017 19:09 Martin Lægland, Publisert på nett.

The search gives me every `09.09.2017`, but not `31.12.2017` on the second line. Which is exactly what I want. I then want to replace all the `09.09.2017s` so they becomes `*09.09.2017*`.

How do I reference `^.*?\K\d+\.\d+\.\d+` in the replace field in notepad++? Earlier I have been able to do this with `*\1*` in the replace field, where `\1` references the regex I've used, but that doesn't seem to work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your previous regex [looked like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47288394/match-first-date-in-line-with-regex) `\K(([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{4}))` with a capturing group set around the whole pattern. That is why `\1` referred to the whole match that was also captured into Group 1.

You may either capture the whole pattern with `(...)` again and use `*\1*`, or  use `$0` backreference instead of `\1`:

```
^.*?\K\d+\.\d+\.\d+
```

replace with

```
*$0*
```

where `$0` is the backreference to the whole match.

[image]

Comment: Besides `$0`, `$&`, `$MATCH`, `${^MATCH}` can be used, too.

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for noticing the continuity of my questions :) I wasn't able to get this to work when I first used Replace (once), but it works when I use Replace All which is what I wanted anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you could use "$&" instead of \1